# Call a service from twig template in symfony 4

Tags: twig, symfony4

I would like to know how I can call a service from twig template directly on Symfony 4. I am using it in each action like this:

```
public function indexAction(TranslatorInterface $translator, NavigationGenerator $navigationGenerator)
    {

        return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
            'navigationItems'=>$navigationGenerator->getNavigation(self::class)
        ]);
    }
```

In the template I call this:

```
{% for navigationItem in navigationItems.topNavigation['left'] %}
    <a href="{{ navigationItem.route }}">{{ navigationItem.label }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In earlier bootstrap versions I could define the service as a global object in config.yml and use it directly from twig like this:

```
{ NavigationGenerator.getNavigation(ControllerName) }
```

Any hint how to do this in Symfony 4? There is no config.yml anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still define twig global variables - they would just go in with the rest of the Twig configuration in `config/packages/twig.yaml`.

An alternative, and maybe better place to put that could be a [Twig function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html). The service that defines the function (or filters) are as much a service as the controllers, and so you would type-hint your `NavigationGenerator` and anything else you needed, in the constructor, for use in the function that is being called from Twig.

Comment: Acutually I will use the service solution, but the twig function seems to be interesting, will use this in future projects